# If there is a public domain list of Japanese words for free download

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Wondering if there is a list of Japanese words for free download (i.e. public domain, not creative commons). Perhaps it is in the form of a:

- Dictionary
- Word frequency list
- Corpus annotation

Wondering if anything such exists.

Comment: See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/7705

Answer (score 2):

You might want to join the JMDict mailing list and discuss that with them.

Answer (score 0):

jisho.org. I believe they have a free api for use

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the [Corpora](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/1074#1074) section of our Resources list?

We have a few options listed there.